# Mock final classes for Instrumentation tests - Gradle issue

Tags: android, junit, powermock

I am trying to use Powermock for mocking static classes.
here is my gradle file dependencies:

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'

androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.2'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.2'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.2'
androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.2'

}
```

The problem is that once I am running the test I get the following Errors:

> :app:preDexDebugAndroidTest
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack\u003dtrue","sources":[{}]}
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack\u003dtrue","sources":[{}]}
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack\u003dtrue","sources":[{}]}
>
> :app:dexDebugAndroidTest
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/powermock/modules/junit4/rule/PowerMockRule;","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack\u003dtrue","sources":[{}]}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebugAndroidTest'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Please advise what is the root cause and How can I mock final classes of Instrumentation tests.

Thanks

Comment: `androidTestCompile` is for instrumentation tests. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to use power mock for instrumentation tests. Is it possible?